# Mapping fetched data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a TreeNode function in react that builds a tree structure of some data.

I have fake data as a starting point:

```
const fakeData = {
 "1234": {
   id: "1234",
   name: "Division",
   address: "string",
   childNodes: []
  }
};
```

When I expand the "Division" node with the "id" 1234, I want to fetch the children of this node. So my fakeData expands to something like this:

I'm using the fetch() method to get data, but I'm unsure of how to pass that data to resolve() method of the Promise. Right now I'm doing this:

```
function fakeAjax(url, id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(result => {
        const nodes = result.map(node => node.id);
        resolve(fakeData[id].childNodes.map(nodes));
      });
  });
}

function fetchChildNodes(id) {
  return fakeAjax(`someUrl`, id);
}

function TreeNode({ id, name }) {
  const [childNodes, setChildNodes] = useState(null);

  // Toggle our display of child nodes
  const toggleExpanded = useCallback(() => {
      fetchChildNodes(id)
        .then(nodes => setChildNodes(nodes.map(node => <TreeNode {...node} />)))
    }
  }, [childNodes]);
```

But this is not passing the relavant data to the resolve method. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things jump out:

1. Your code is using the [explicit promise creation anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). `fetch` returns a promise, there's no need to wrap `new Promise` around it. It's not the problem, but it's *a* problem, not least because the way `fakeAjax` is written, if the ajax call fails, the promise returned by `fakeAjax` is never rejected (and never fulfilled, it just stays pending forever).
2. You're calling `map` passing in a non-function as the mapping function:

   ```
   const nodes = result.map(node => node.id);
   resolve(fakeData[id].childNodes.map(nodes));
   // Here −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
   ```

   That doesn't make any sense. `map` accepts a function, not an array.
3. Your code is getting hit by the footgun in the `fetch` API that almost everyone else is also hit by: You need to check that the request worked at the HTTP level. `fetch` only rejects when there's a network error, not an HTTP error (more on my blog [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html)).
4. I assume your ajax call returns actual node data that you should be passing directly to `TreeNode`, not modifying (and certainly not turning into an array of just `id` values).

So something like:

```
function fetchJSON(url) {
    return fetch(url)
      .then(res => {
          if (!res.ok) {
              throw new Error("HTTP error " + res.status);
          }
          return res.json();
      });
}

function fetchChildNodes(id) {
    return fetchJSON(`someUrl`, id);
}
```

The mapping of node data to `TreeNode` is happening in `TreeNode`, so I don't think you need to do anything in `fetchChildNodes`.